# grails mail configuration from database

Tags: email, grails, grails-plugin

I am new to grails.

I wants to configure mail and set host, port, uname and password from **database**.

How do i made change on config.groovey

Please suggest me suitable plugin also.

Comment: I was searching google about this issue. Did you solve it ? Can you tell me ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instread of giving configuration details(hostname,port,username,password) in congif.groovy,

I have made One class and set the parameters from database.

My issue has been solved now.

Comment: Can you tell me how to write it in other class ?

Answer (score 0):

Hardik,
We have used http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail with great success. It is very easy to setup and use. 
Good luck,
Dmitry.

Comment: I have also used this mail plugin.But the Problem is in Configuration, how do i specify the values such as host = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, username = "youracount@gmail.com" ,password = "yourpassword" **FROM DATABASE**.

Comment: Why would u want to do that from the database??? Anyways if you get your values from the database u can just override the config via grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.host="$myValueFromDATABASE"

Comment: Hello DmitryB,  I need mail setting from database because In case of database you don't need to restart the server while changing the values of mail setting, In case of config.groovy  if you wants to change the setting, you must have to restart the server. Thanks